# Finding the sum of $1 \cdot 2x + 2 \cdot 3x^{2} + 3 \cdot 4x^{3} + \dots$ .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is the sum of $1 \cdot 2x + 2 \cdot 3x^{2} + 3 \cdot 4x^{3} + \dots$ ?

I have been stuck on this problem with no direction. I have tried multiplying the sequence with $x$ and trying out $S-Sx$ but have gotten nowhere. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  what's the anti-derivative?

Comment: Looks like the derivative of a well-known power series.

Comment: Little hint - $\frac{s}{x} = \frac{2!}{0!} + \frac{3!}{1!} x + \frac{4!}{2!} x^2 + \frac{5!}{3!} x^3 + \cdots = \frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d} x^2} \left[ x^2 + \cdots \right]$ etc… :-P

Comment: HINT:$$\sum_{n\ge 1}n(n+1)x^n=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n\ge 1}nx^{n+1}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=\ge1}(n+2)x^{n+1}-2\sum_{n\ge 1}x^{n+1}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$F'(x)=S=1\cdot2x+2\cdot3x^2+3\cdot4x^3+\cdots$

$F(x)=x^2+2x^3+3x^4+\cdots=x^2(1+2x+3x^2+\cdots)=\dfrac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my hint, you have:

$$\frac{s}{x} = \frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d} x^2}\left[ x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + \cdots \right] = \frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d} x^2}\left[ 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + \cdots \right] = \frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d} x^2}\left[ \frac{1}{1 - x} \right] = \frac{2}{(1 - x)^3}$$

(you can add $1+x$ to the sum in square brackets because $1+x$ has second derivative equal to $0$), hence:

$$ s = \frac{2x}{(1 - x)^3}\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$S=2x+6x^2+12x^3+20x^4+\cdots$$

$$S(1-x)=2x+(6-2)x^2+(12-6)x^3+(20-12)x^4+\cdots=V\text{(say)}$$

$$V(1-x)=2x+x^2(4-2)+x^3(6-4)+x^4(8-6)+\cdots=\dfrac{2x}{1-x}\iff|x|<1$$

Can you take it from here?

**See** : [this](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.06/h/rose1.html)